# Why are parenthesis required when using members of union type bound to `let`?

Tags: f#

Having the following type:

```
type MyType =
    | MyType of string
```

I tried to do this:

```
let myFunc x =
    let MyType y = x
    y // Compilation error
```

This causes a compilation error:

> The value or constructor **y** is not defined.

However, if I put parenthesis around `MyType y`, the code compiles.

```
let myFunc x =
    let (MyType y) = x
    y // Compiles successfully
```

What is the difference between the two versions?

Comment: Or specify a type for y:

    let y : MyType = x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version declares a function named `MyType` with one parameter named `y`. This parameter is only available in the body of this function, so you get an error when you try to access this parameter outside of the function.

The second version destructures a value with constructor named `MyType`, binding its content to identifier `y`. This identifier is then available until the current scope ends.

The parentheses as necessary to distinguish destructuring from function declaration.

In this particular case you can simplify the destructuring by moving it into the parameter list:

```
let myFunc (MyType y) =
    y
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was suspecting that the first version might be a function declaration, but I was thrown off by the fact that with unions you can do `match x with | MyType y`, without any parenthesis required. This is most likely allowed, because there can be no ambiguity in such context.